# Android : Removing unused resolution specific drawables on first run

Tags: android

I have been developing a rather large application for tablets.
Since I do not want to be unnecessarily using up hardware storage space, I was wanting to remove resolution specific drawables.

To be more clear, if the tablet using my app is running with HDPI resolution, would there be any "risk" if I were to delete the MDPI and XHDPI resources ?

It is my understanding that tablets do not change resolution and so these resources would never be used and are therefore just taking up storage space.

Is there any good reason to not do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is my understanding that tablets do not change resolution and so these resources would never be used and are therefore just taking up storage space.

Actually, starting with Android N you can change the density of your device at runtime, with a new option in Accessibility settings called *Display size*. If you'd like to see how it looks and read how it works then Android police has [a nice post about it](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/10/android-n-feature-spotlight-easily-change-your-devices-display-dpi-with-screen-zoom/). Some custom ROMs were doing this on older versions of Android as well.

However, that wouldn't break your app. Android is smart enough to use the closes DPI version of your drawable that you included (or in your case, the only one) and up- or downscale the image. The worst that could happen is you get some blurriness or other scaling artifacts.

So there are some downsides and slight risks, but nothing too scary. Google actually advises using single DPI builds for large apps, they even provide [APK splits](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits) functionality in gradle to make it easier to generate APKs containing only single DPI drawables.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is going to be used only on one specific device, then go and delete the unnecessary drawables. Btw HDPI is not the resolution, but the density of the dots on the screen. If you put your only resource in drawable-hdpi, then it's going to be scaled up / down on devices with different densities, which may look distored in the worst case. But be aware that if you put the resource in the drawable folder (no density specified) it's not going to be scaled in any case (which is not what you're going for).

You may also take a look at different approaches for making your images smaller like color indexing, etc.

Answer (score -2):

There is a tool called [shrinkResources](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) , it removes resources that are unused, at **build time**

Add this to your **build.gradle**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice tool, but it's not going to remove the drawables from the folders for different densities, which is what Simon asks for.